# Helgrind reports synchronization errors in simple boost::asio::thread_pool program

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool, valgrind

I'm experimenting with boost::asio::thread_pool and helgrind reports errors in a simple program that has empty task function. Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/post.hpp>


int main() {
    ushort thread_num = 4;
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool(thread_num);

    auto task = []() {};

    for (ushort i = 0; i < thread_num; ++i)
        boost::asio::post(pool, task);

    pool.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the helgrind output:

```
==266706== Thread #1 is the program's root thread
==266706== 
==266706== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==266706== 
==266706== Thread #1: pthread_cond_{signal,broadcast}: dubious: associated lock is not held by any thread
==266706==    at 0x48405D6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==266706==    by 0x11508D: bool boost::asio::detail::posix_event::maybe_unlock_and_signal_one<boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock>(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x111AAD: boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_event::maybe_unlock_and_signal_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x11361E: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::wake_one_thread_and_unlock(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x1132C4: boost::asio::detail::scheduler::post_immediate_completion(boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, bool) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x10DD99: void boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type::post<boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<main::{lambda()#1}>, std::allocator<void> >(boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<main::{lambda()#1}>&&, std::allocator<void> const&) const (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x10DBFB: void boost::asio::detail::initiate_post::operator()<main::{lambda()#1}&, boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type const&>(main::{lambda()#1}&, boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type const&) const (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x10DB82: void boost::asio::async_result<main::{lambda()#1}, void ()>::initiate<boost::asio::detail::initiate_post, {lambda()#1}&, boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type const&>(boost::asio::detail::initiate_post&&, {lambda()#1}&, boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type const&) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x10DB54: std::enable_if<void ()::async_result_has_initiate_memfn<main::{lambda()#1}&, void ()>::value, boost::asio::async_result<std::decay<void ()::async_result_has_initiate_memfn>::type, main::{lambda()#1}&>::return_type>::type boost::asio::async_initiate<main::{lambda()#1}&, void (), boost::asio::detail::initiate_post, boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type const&>(boost::asio::detail::initiate_post&&, void (&)()::async_result_has_initiate_memfn, boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type const&) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x10DB12: boost::asio::async_result<std::decay<main::{lambda()#1}&>::type, void ()>::return_type boost::asio::post<boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type, main::{lambda()#1}&>(boost::asio::thread_pool::executor_type const&, std::decay&&, std::enable_if<boost::asio::is_executor<boost::asio::async_result<std::decay<main::{lambda()#1}&>::type, void ()>::return_type>::value, void>::type*) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x10DABD: boost::asio::async_result<std::decay<main::{lambda()#1}&>::type, void ()>::return_type boost::asio::post<boost::asio::thread_pool, main::{lambda()#1}&>(boost::asio::thread_pool&, std::decay&&, std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<boost::asio::thread_pool, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value, void>::type*) (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
==266706==    by 0x10DA11: main (in /home/arno/Programming/test/a.out)
```

Comment: Where does it report a data race? There is only one "dubious" diagnostic message, which isn't even indicating any data race.

Comment: @Ext3h You are right, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal

> The pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() functions may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() have associated with the condition variable during their waits; however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal().

It's just a diagnostic warning indicating a common cause for inefficient scheduling around condition variables. You get spurious wakes if you (as a producer) don't keep the mutex locked while signaling. E.g. it's possible that your update of the CV variable has been processed as soon as you unlocked the mutex, so your signal is then causing another unnecessary wakeup without any changed state.

Keeping the mutex locked for the whole update of the CV variable as well as signaling in contrast is handled efficiently, as the consumer has registered pairwise on both the mutex and CV, and signaling the CV directly puts the consumer on the wait-list for the mutex without activating the thread even once.

That's just inefficient though, not a logic error. And Helgrind only reported it as "dubious", not as an error.

Comment: Do you mean that this happening inside the boost library and my code is correct?

Comment: Yes, the warning is triggered by the boost library.